# How to save linux command?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line, grep

I am using

```
 grep -r [^a-zA-Z0-9]myVariableName[^a-zA-Z0-9] -n JS_files/
```

as mygrep file

```
grep -r [^a-zA-Z0-9]$1[^a-zA-Z0-9] -n JS_files/
```

and then

```
sh mygrep myVariableName
```

But then I lose the highlighting of the word in corresponding line in grep output. How can I acheive similar effect without losing the grep ubuntu terminal color highlights?

also my grep is by default ignoring the case, how can I force case sensitiveness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `grep` command is using `--color=auto`:

```
$ alias grep
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

So you can still get the color adding this block in your `grep`:

```
grep --color=auto -r [^a-zA-Z0-9]$1[^a-zA-Z0-9] -in JS_files/
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

> also my grep is by default ignoring the case, how can I force case
>   sensitiveness?

It means that your grep is using `-i`:

> ```
>  -i, --ignore-case
> ```
>
> Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files.  (-i is specified by POSIX.)

You have two options:

1) Try using the default grep with `\grep`. It will bypass any alias (see [\curl … | bash … what's the slash for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951772/curl-bash-whats-the-slash-for) for more info):

```
\grep --color=auto -r [^a-zA-Z0-9]$1[^a-zA-Z0-9] -in JS_files/
```

2) Change the `grep` definition in your `~/.bashrc` to the one you want. By now it will something like:

```
alias grep="grep --color=auto -i"
```

Comment: also my grep is by default ignoring the case, how can I force case sensitiveness?

Comment: I tried searching for "vector" using \grep but lines containing "Vector" are also returned.

Comment: Try usign `\grep` as I comment in my updated answer.

Comment: I tried \grep, I dont know why its working case insensitive by default

Comment: Type `alias grep` to know what's your default `grep` alias. As I comment in my answer, you can change it in your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Add to end of the `~/.bashrc` file

```
alias grep="/bin/grep --color=auto"
```